# Sort data frame in Pandas and draw a bar graph

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I have the result data frame and i want to sort index column of result data frame. result data frame stores all the groupby operatation previously performed

Here is output of result data frame.

[image]

I want to sort index column. data types of all the column are int64. Right now it short data by alphabets. I want to draw bar graphs with sorted data.

Comment: What does it return when you type: type(result.index[0])

Answer (score 0):

You index contains string representations of dates/periods which first need to be converted before sorting.

```
result['dates'] = [dt.datetime.strptime(d, "%b %Y") for d in result.index]
result.sort('dates', inplace=True)
```

To remove the column,

```
result.drop('dates', inplace=True, axis=1)
```

To use Pandas Periods (which are good for plotting data):

```
result['periods'] = [pd.Period(dt.datetime.strptime(d, "%b %Y"), "M") for d in result.index]
```

To set this as the index:

```
result = result.reset_index().set_index('periods')
```